# How flood risk is determined

Tags: statistics, hydrology

If you live in a 1% AEP flood zone, you have a 50.3% chance of being flooded in a typical lifetime (70 years), and a 15.6% chance of being flooded twice in this period.

My Solution for 50.3% = 1 - exp(-70/100)

I am not quite sure about how to get 15.6%.

Will appreciate any though on that.